# How to remove a tint on a specific wordpress page

Tags: css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am having troubles trying to remove a tint on the home page only.

I believe my page ID is

9148

[image]

Here is the div I am trying to change

[image]

```
 .page-id-9148 .hero-tint { 
 display: none !important;
```

}

This is the CSS I have used which does not work.

```
     .page-id-9148 .hero-tint { 
     display: none !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it may be happening that your css is not called correctly because your css is correct.

But there is a more professional way to solve this since you want the element not to appear on screen.

I will give 3 ways to do this correctly, remembering that the first is the most appropriate.

**1 ° Adding a conditional to display the code.**
Since you do not want to display this element only on the homepage, it is best to put a condition in the php code where this html is called.
Search your theme / plugin where it is added and place a conditional similar to this:

```
<?php if(  !is_home() && !is_front_page() ): ?>
    <div class="hero-tint"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

OR

```
<?php if(  !is_page( 9148 ) ): ?>
    <div class="hero-tint"></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**2° Removing via CSS**
In your case your css is correct but perhaps it is being called before the css that is updating  or is not being called at all. To make sure it is being called locate the footer.php file of your theme and look for the wp_footer () code and add a code right after. something like that:

```
    wp_footer(); 
?>
<style>
    .page-id-9148 .hero-tint {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

**3º Removing via javascript**
Search the theme for the file footer.php and put something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.page-id-9148 .hero-tint').remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: In the html editor on page id 9148, add this:

```
<style>.hero-tint {display: none !important;}</style>
```

Option 2: Edit footer.php in your theme and add this anywhere:

```
<?php if (is_page('9148') ):?>
<style>
    .hero-tint {display: none !important;}
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```